Azure Key Vault endpoint is not set on Local Visual Studio code
I am following the steps outlined in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo-csharp to deploy ChatGPT and azure search. When running the following command to start on a local client host, I get the error below it.
dotnet run --project ./app/backend/MinimalApi.csproj --urls=http://localhost:7181/
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Azure Key Vault endpoint is not set. at MinimalApi.Extensions.KeyVaultConfigurationBuilderExtensions.ConfigureAzureKeyVault(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
AZURE_KEY_VAULT_ENDPOINT is identically specified on the local Visual Studio code and in Azure Container App Environment variable.

This was a case of a mix up on folder structure on my part and for some reason had the .env file is to folders.
